# What's wrong with my argument about entanglement entropy in QFT being time-independent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, entropy, quantum-entanglement, conformal-field-theory

Let's say we need to compute the entanglement entropy (EE) of a subsystem $A$ ($A=[0,L]$, $L>0$) in a 2D CFT.

The density matrix of the total system (i.e., the real axis) is given by
$$
\rho(t)=\text{e}^{-iHt}\rho_0~\text{e}^{iHt},
$$
where $\rho_0$ is certian time-independent positive semi-definite matrix with unit trace.

Then, I shall argue that **the EE of $A$ should be time-independent.**

##### **My argument:**

$$
\begin{align}
\because&~\text{The Hamiltonian } H=\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}T_{00}dx=\int_{A}T_{00}dx+\int_{\bar{A}}T_{00}dx=H_A+H_{\bar A},\\
\therefore&~\text{the evolution operator}~\text{e}^{\pm iHt}=\text{e}^{\pm i(H_A+H_{\bar A})~t}=\text{e}^{\pm i  H_A~t}\otimes\text{e}^{\pm iH_{\bar A}~t}.\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore the reduced density matrix of $A$ reads:
$$
\rho_A(t)=\text{Tr}_{\bar A}[\rho(t)]=e^{-iH_A~t}\text{Tr}_{\bar A}[e^{-iH_\bar A~t}\rho_0e^{iH_\bar A~t}]e^{iH_A~t}=e^{-iH_A~t}\text{Tr}_{\bar A}[\rho_0]e^{iH_A~t}.
$$
Since $\rho_A(t)$ and $\text{Tr}_{\bar A}[\rho_0]$ differ by only a unitary transformation, the EE obtained by $\rho_A(t)$ should be the same for the EE obtained by $\text{Tr}_{\bar A}[\rho_0]$. What's more,
$$
S_A\big(\text{Tr}_{\bar A}[\rho_0]\big)=-\text{Tr}_A\big[\text{Tr}_{\bar A}[\rho_0]\log \text{Tr}_{\bar A}[\rho_0]\big]
$$
is time-independent, which finally leads to a time-indepentent $S_A\big(\rho_A(t)\big)$. $\square$

#### Contradiction with known results:

The result derived by the above argument is contradict with many known results.

For exapmle, in 2014, [T. Takayanagi et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0702) found that the $S_A$ for  a locally excited state (A state generated by acting a local operator $O(-x)~(x>0)$ on the vaccum) behaves like
$$S_A(t)=
\begin{cases}
S_{A,vacuum},&t<x~\text{or}~t>x+L,\\
S_{A,vacuum}+\log d_O,& x<t<x+L,
\end{cases}
$$
where $S_{A,vacuum}=\frac{c}{3}\log\frac{L}{\epsilon}$ stands for the EE of $A$ when the total system is in  the vacuum, $d_O$ stands for the quantum dimension of $O$. Obviously their result is time dependent.

#### My question:

Physically, I agree that in some states the entanglement entropy of the subsystem should be time dependent, but what is the problem with my argument?

Comment: You’re assuming that $\rho_0$ and the region A is time independent. But neither of those has to be true.

Comment: @Prahar Thanks for the comment, but sorry i can't get your point. What do you mean by "the region A is time independent"

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly making a very strong assumption in your argument. Given
$$
H=H_A+H_{\bar A},
$$
$$
e^{\pm iHt}=e^{\pm i(H_A+H_{\bar A})~t}
$$
is true, but your next step
$$
e^{\pm i(H_A+H_{\bar A})~t} =e^{\pm i  H_A~t} e^{\pm iH_{\bar A}~t}.
$$
only holds if $\left[ H_A, H_\bar{A}\right]=0$, recall the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! : ) You're probably right, and I need to take some time to think about it.  BTW, why do you say that "$[H_A,H_{\bar{A}}]=0$ is a very strong assumption"? Could you please comment more on that? Thanks again! ^_^

Comment: Well, saying that $H_A$ and $H_\bar{A}$ can be simultaneously diagonalized rather constrains what models you are considering. It is certainly not generally true. In particular, you're ruling out many interacting lattice models with CFT low-energy descriptions.